# test set R2 is higher than cross-validated R2. why?

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn

I am running a random forest regression and have encountered a situation where my test-set performance is markedly better than my training/validation performance (as measured by R2), I'm unsure how/why this should be the case.

For clarity, I initially started with a dataset of over 1000 features and 400 observations. Using K-fold CV with K=5, I have applied removed highly correlated features, and run recursive feature elimination to bring the feature-set down to about 90. I have then used gridsearch to fine-tune hyperparameters and have achieved a cross-validated R2 of 0.2, which is slightly above average for my particular problem.

My thinking then was to obtain some more data to run as a test set, expecting this to score less than my CV performance but hopefully not too much lower. So, having found 65 more observations, I used the optimized random forest to predict target values in this new test set. Surprisingly, I am getting R2 on this test set of 0.26. I am at a loss to explain why the test set performance should be so much higher than the k-fold performance, given that all the tuning/feature selection was done on this dataset.

I am assuming that I must have screwed up somewhere. I've tried googling the answer but cannot seem to make sense of similar queries.

Comment: With a test set that small, it's likely just by random chance that the $R^2$ value is so high.  The fact that the training sets are so small relative to your feature size are likely to cause a lot of variance, meaning that you'll likely see varying $R^2$ values as you apply your model to different data sets.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Out of curiosity, your comment of "the training sets are so small relative to your feature size" sounds like the "curse of dimensionality" problem. Have I understood that right?

Comment: I agree with @NickKoprowicz; one thing to check is how the R2 varies across folds in your CV.  (Is that R2 the average across the fold splits, or the score on the entire dataset's cross-val-scores?)

Comment: @Ben Reiniger. Thanks. It's come from the cross_val_predict function in sklearn.model_selection, so I'm guessing that it's based on the entire dataset cross-val scores. Because of the nature in which I collected the data (collected 1 dataset first, and then went to find more after), I'm assuming I could be unwittingly introducing some sort of bias given that the combined datasets are not exactly randomly sampled.... Based on your collective comments I'm assuming a reasonable test might be to combine both datasets and randomly split.

Comment: I have re-sampled the dataset a few times and, as you speculated, am generating test-set results across a wide range (between 0.09 and 0.30). Crucially, they are both above and below the CV score. Thanks for your help.